# How to increase TCP bandwidth in Iperf

Tags: tcp, bandwidth, iperf

In IPERF we have a option to increase the target bandwidth with the option "-b 100m" but in TCP i dont see a option in both JPERF 2.0.2 and also in cli command. Please let me know how can i increase the bandwidth for my throughput testing since i can only receive the traffic at a rate of 20mbps .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the TCP window with `-w`. Multiply your desired throughput by the latency to get a starting point for the window value. If you wanted to get 50mbps on a link with 40ms rtt:

`50000000 * .04 = 2000000 bytes`

Answer (score 0):

For TCP, you cannot set target bandwidth. As for TCP, its sending rate is regulated by flow and congestion control which is determined by RTT and loss. For example, in slow-start phase, the sender can send double number of packets every RTT. In congestion-avoidance state, the congestion window size will be cut by half (or 1/3 in TCP Cubic) once a loss detected.

However, -w can set the sending/receiving window size. If your window size is too small, the total throughput may be bottle-necked by it. So, usually try a large window size, e.g. 65535. Remember a large window size just makes sure your TCP rate would not be bottle-necked by window size, it does not "guarantee" a large throughput.